# What network library should I use to write a server to handle 300k plus clients?

Tags: asynchronous, twisted, gevent

I am making a first attempt to write a iOS/Android poker application like Zynga Poker, where i must handle up to 300k clients connections at a time, and much more as my user base grows. Clients will connect to unfilled rooms with 5-9 players interacting with other, and have the ability to message each other.
I've done quite a bit of research and it seems like Twisted Matrix is the de facto standard, but I'm also highly interested in gevent because it uses coroutines rather than callbacks to handle asynchronous programming. But one thing that worries me is some programmer from this site, http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2288081 wrote this

"That is why I don't understand why many high profile realtime web startups (like Convore), still using inferior solutions, like Python eventlib or gevent, which at most let them handle hundreds-to-thousands of clients."

Is this true? So I'm torn between which framework to use. Or is there something better out there? And is 300k connections asking to much of python? If it is, I am willing to do the server in java or C++, but I would rather use python.

Comment: 300k connections _on what architecture and hardware?_

Comment: I'm planning on having one global service to handle login, messaging, and load balancing, while other servers will handle however many rooms with the actual gameplay. Im planning on Using Amazon EC2

Comment: Just want to point out that Twisted is perfectly compatible with coroutines.  Coroutines are orthogonal to an event-driven network engine.  See inlineCallbacks and corotwine for more information about how to use your preferred programming style with Twisted.

Answer (score 5):

300,000 concurrent, active connections is too many to reasonably support in a single process or on a single computer, regardless of what language you're using.  If your program needs to do anything with the data at all, you're going to need more hardware.

Let's do some back of the envelope math to back this up.

Let's say that, on average, your users click their mouse or tap a key or otherwise do something once every 5 seconds or so.  That's 60,000 read events per second.  Now, let's say there are 5 players in each game, which means an additional 300,000 write events per second, assuming you have to update all the players for each of these events.  So: 360,000 bits of "things" to compute per second - assuming you just need to compute some bytes for input and output and you don't have any computationally intensive game logic (like A.I. players) to invoke.

Let's say you're using a [M3 Double Extra Large](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) instance, the largest that amazon currently offers.  That's 8 virtual cores.  Assuming for the moment that your program is purely parallelizable, that means that every one of these input or output events in your game (including all database activity, external web service API calls, etc) needs to be dealt with in 0.00002 seconds.  Now, that leaves you with absolutely no overhead to deal with load spikes, so you'll really want to cut that in half to have any reasonable hope of holding up in case traffic varies, which means 0.00001 seconds per event.  That is a pretty hard limit of ten *microseconds* for all of your game's code to execute; most of the time this sort of responsiveness is measured in milliseconds instead.  On my (reasonably fast) desktop computer, it takes almost two microseconds just to go from one call of `time.time()` to the next, if there is no other code in between.  Even finely tuned C code can't get a lot of useful work done in a microsecond.

Which means that, if you want to approach this level of scale, you really, really need to be able to run your service on more than one server at a time.  And, once your service can run on *two* servers, generally it's not a big deal to put it on three, or five, or a hundred.

While I would very much like to tell you to [use Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com) (and there are lots of great reasons that you should), the real conclusion here is that you can use *anything you please* and it will "scale up" to your hundreds of thousands of connections just fine, provided that you write it in such a way that it doesn't depend on a single server servicing all your requests.  At the point where you have a service actually processing 300k live, concurrent connections, the difference in performance between using gevent or Twisted or Tornado or Eventlet or EventMachine – if there is in fact any difference at all – will be the difference between, let's say, leasing 50 and 55 instances from Amazon.  (And, it's hard to say which one will be faster, since it sort of depends what you'll do with it.)  The difference between profiling your *own* code and keeping close watch over its performance as you develop it, however, is the difference between leasing 500 machines and leasing 50.